# past encounter of homosexuality?

Tags: sharia, punishment, homosexuality

i have a question i would like to ask. in 2007/2008 i had an encounter with my cousin, we where like 11/12 years old. basically we had found out what dry humping was and for jokes we tried it. it was a one time encounter and after that had forgot it and never really talked or done anything like it. now im 19 and had totally forgot about this however it had just popped up in my mind and is doing my head in. keep thinking what had possessed me to do such an act.

it was done out of ignorance, now what i would like to know is that is this act a act of homosexuality. and what constitutes to act of homosexuality.

thanks

Comment: I infer that your cousin is a guy, in which yes dry-humping another man is a homosexual act. (For homosexuality haram in Islam is two men who commit a sexual act together.) I have a question though, at the time did you knowingly commit the sin, or did you commit it unknowingly?

Comment: i had committed it unknowingly. however becuase it was so long ago my mind is playing games with me and i cant exactly come to terms of what had actually happened.

Answer (score 2):

In Islam Allah (swt) is most-just, most-forgiving. (Partly as a non-Muslim, which I love to hear.)

This Hadith answers your question (bolded part in your reference):

> On the authority of Ibn Abbas (may Allah be pleased with him), that
>   the Messenger of Allah (peace and blessings of Allah be upon him)
>   said:
>
> Verily Allah **has pardoned** [or been lenient with] for me my ummah:
>   their mistakes, **their forgetfulness**, and that which they have been
>   forced to do under duress. A hasan hadeeth related by Ibn Majah, and
>   al-Bayhaqee and others. - [40 Hadith Nawawi 39](http://sunnah.com/nawawi40/39)

According to Islamic scholars (I cannot cite, but I will ask my Muslim friend when I have the chance) you should repent make Tawbah and make a strong pledge to Allah (swt) you will try to avoid such incidents in the future.

Note: You have not sinned in Islam, Islam is very forgiving in the case of accidental sin.

> When those come to thee who believe in Our signs, Say: "Peace be on
>   you: Your Lord hath inscribed for Himself (the rule of) mercy: verily,
>   **if any of you did evil in ignorance, and thereafter repented**, and
>   amend (his conduct), lo! He is Oft-forgiving, Most Merciful.
>   - [Qur'an 6:54]

**Sin in Islam is classified as:**

Sin is sin, but sin is punishable when one has knowingly committed sin. (Unknowingly they will not be forgiven, but when they find out what they did was sin, they must repent.)

Comment: thanks very much. also in regards to homosexuality and what constitues towards it, does things like spanking another guy constitute towards it. only asking this becuase alot of people seem to do it as a joke and i see it as being wrong. also doing similiar acts like this as a joke is it still considered as homosexuality.

Comment: @anon14 What do you mean by "spanking"?

Comment: oh like a slap on the bottom

Comment: Spanking in form of discipline, probably not, and as a joke probably not. However is that act you do is strictly sexual, such as dry-humping (it mimics the movement of sex) then it is haram. However if you "spank" someone the same sex with the sole reason for sexual lust, then yes it is probably haram. Also no problem, learning about Islam is fun. :-)